# Outlook displaying â„¢ instead of ™

Tags: c#, html, utf-8, outlook

I am trying to send an email from my application with a subject line that has ™
When viewed in browser it displays correctly. But, when viewed in outlook it displays â„¢ . I tried copying the trademark symbol from charmap.exe. But, it did not work. Any help?

```
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 04:25:31 -0600
Subject: MyBrandâ„¢ New Action Notification- December Release:test...
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="boundary"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: SMailer
```

Comment: What package you use for sending that email?

Comment: I am not sure what package means. But, mine is a MVC application and we send emails through a third party applicaiton PMTA. Is this what your asking about?

Comment: For me it looks like that PMTA is encoding everything not in UTF8 by default, and since that ™ goes out of standard ascii, it causes problems. Not sure how to solve it though, needs more investigation.

Comment: I suspect the browser is guessing the encoding correctly, which looks like it's ending up as UTF-8. Perhaps you can specific the header encoding or perhaps you can encode the header yourself using the syntax demonstrated here: http://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering your HTML markup. So, I'd recommend opening the email murkup in Word first.

You may find the following articles helpful where supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties are described in depth:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please show how you create the message and the resulting MIME headers. You need to make sure you correctly encode all the Unicode characters in the Subject and other MIME headers.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the header that i am adding.

Comment: You must encode the non-ASCII characters correctly: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?MyBrand=E2=84=A2_New_Action_Notification?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?-_December_Release:test?=